# Formatting for script letters to match latex

Tags: output-formatting, fonts

In the [Wolfram Documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/ScriptL.html) for \ℓ, there are two formats for the script letter shown. How can I select the first format, which looks more like "\ell" symbol in latex? For instance, I have the following input:

```
Graphics[{Text[Style[Subscript[ℓ, 2], FontSize -> 20], {1/6, 1/30}]}]
```

the output appears as

[image]

I get the same output if I use:

```
Graphics[{Text[
   Style[ToExpression["\\ell_{2}", TeXForm], FontSize -> 20], {1/6, 1/30}]}]
```

I've been playing around with various formatting options but haven't figured it out. How can I get Mathematica to output the curlier version of `ℓ`?

Comment: I see this on my machine (OS X): http://i.stack.imgur.com/GLKwl.png  This is also the second format shown on my machine on the doc page.

Comment: Instead of `ToExpression["\ell", TeXForm]` you should use `ToExpression["\\ell", TeXForm]`.  It is important to double the `\`, even though it works in this case.  Of course this makes absolutely no difference to your question.

Comment: You can use `TraditionalForm` to select the first form ... `TraditionalForm@Style[\[ScriptL], FontSize -> 64]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I do see the correct formatting if I Input Subscript[\[ScriptL], 2] by itself. Perhaps the issue may be what happens within Graphics. In my ToExpression, I do have the extra backslash, however, it looks like it ran away during copy/paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In v10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64:

```
Graphics[{Text @ Style[Subscript[\[ScriptL], 2], FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> #]}, 
   ImageSize -> 50] & /@ {"Times", "Arial", "Mathematica1"}
```

[image]

Terser and possibly safer code using styles from the core stylesheet:

```
Graphics[{Text @ Style[Subscript[\[ScriptL], 2], 30, #]}, 
   ImageSize -> 50] & /@ {"TR", "SR", "MR", "MB"}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. The "TR" font is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!